# All content of one page shifted to the left

Tags: pages, blog

I am new to Wordpress and am trying to start a personal blog just for fun. I selected a theme but realized after a few weeks I didn’t really like it. I switched themes and everything has been going good! A couple things got shaken up when I switched, so I’ve just been going over each individual page and making tiny edits just to make sure everything looks good. One page in particular shifted everything completely to the left of my screen. I have no idea why this happened and I can’t seem to center everything again, but I thought whatever, it will look fine when publishing. Nope! When I hit publish, everything is squished on top of each other. Literally… every single letter is placed on top of each other- so the whole page is soooo long. I cannot figure out why this happened or how to undo it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To effectively assist you with your blog site issue, we require more specific details about your setup. There are various factors that could be contributing to the problem, such as your theme, plugins, browser compatibility, or the content you're using. Without these details, it's challenging to pinpoint the exact cause of the issue. To help us help you, please provide the following information:

**Theme Name**: Share the name of your current WordPress theme. This information is essential because different themes have different settings and potential issues.

**Website Screenshots**: Providing screenshots of the problem areas can be immensely helpful. This allows us to visually identify the issue and provide more accurate solutions.

In general, when you're new to WordPress, it's advisable to choose a popular and well-tested theme with a strong reputation in the community. These themes are often more stable and come with extensive support resources.

Additionally, as a beginner in WordPress, it's a good practice to rely on the theme's built-in features and avoid extensive customizations, especially if you're not experienced with coding. WordPress offers a wide range of both free and commercial themes, so you can find one that suits your needs without delving into custom development. This approach typically results in a smoother and more manageable experience for new users.